# How to call WCF Service on Local Machine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mef, wcf-binding

We have an environment where multiple WCF services are hosted on a single VM and (multiple VM in) server farm behind a fire wall. There are certain services that make calls to other services. Currently we call these services over http. The call gets routed to the load balancer, and each call is routed to any one of the VMs.

For performance reasons, we want to call service on local machine. If possible we want to avoid overhead of serialization and deserialization and directly call it (using MEF?). I would like to know how other people are handling this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just set up an additional endpoint for local machine.

[NetNamedPipeBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

"Provides a secure and reliable binding that is optimized for on-machine communication."

Comment: I will try it . But what is the  serialization used?

Comment: I don't know how NamedPipeBinding serializes but I know it is optimized for on-machine communication and that seems to be your question.   I don't think you can get away without serializing as it is not an process call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the web service project on to your local machine and create a virtual directory for that on your machine and point to this from your code then you can point to it locally and also debug..

Answer (score 0):

You could start the service on your local machine and modify the configuration files to only use your localhost on debug mode and the production VM's on release mode.